# How to stop this message: "Would you like to receive official Jupyter news?"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm running jupyterlab 3.6.1 via docker, and I keep seeing this message when I relaunch:

`Would you like to receive official Jupyter news?`

Is there a config/environment variable to disable this? Unfortunately it doesn't go away unless I explicitly click on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disable this using the command described in:
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/announcements.html

```
jupyter labextension disable "@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:announcements"
```

Comment: I have to say, it's incredibly annoying that this was *enabled* by default!